# How can I split the following string based on the starting '#' character and ending character '#' in TSql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So if I had this string: This is to inform #Department# and #Employees#  of our organization.I just want these two words  #Department# and #Employees#

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here?

Comment: I need #Department# and #Employees# in 2 separate rows like 1.#Department# 2.#Employees#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a **Split** function in your database

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

**THEN USE THE BELOW LINE OF CODE TO GET THE APPROPRIATE OUTPUT**

```
declare @str varchar(100) ='This is to inform #Department# and #Employees# of out.............'


SELECT data from  [dbo].[Split]  (@str,'#')
WHERE ID%2=0
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for. Thank you. But the output is 1.Department 2.Employee. I need the hash tags too like 1.#Department# 2.#Employees#.

Answer (score 1):

Are you lokoing for this

```
declare @string varchar(100) ='This is to inform #Department# and #Employees# of out.............'
,@string_1st_part varchar(100)


declare @table table (col  varchar(100) )

while (CHARINDEX (' #',@string) >0)
begin
 set @string =substring (@string,CHARINDEX (' #',@string)+2,len(@string) )
 set @string_1st_part =substring (@string,1,CHARINDEX ('# ',@string))
 insert into @table
 select  '#'+@string_1st_part
end

select *from  @table
```

Comment: I need #Department# and #Employees# in 2 separate rows like 1.#Department#
2.#Employees#

Comment: Shiju Sir, I need the starting and ending hash tags for each row. 1.#Department# 2.#Employees# . I could also have many words starting with "#" and ending in "#". So if I had this string: This is to inform #Department# and #Employees# of #our# organization. I need ouput as
1.#Department# 2.#Employees#  3.#our# and so on. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Try Now.Edited the answer

Comment: Thank you Shiju .Got what i needed but the thing is the string now has to end with a ' .'(space and dot). i Really appreaciate your help . Thank you once again :)